My proof of $\delta_0\left(t^2-|x|^2\right)=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2} t} \mathrm{~d} \sigma_{C_0^{+}}(t, x)$
Here is the proof of 
Lemma 4.10. On $\mathbb{R}^{1+3} \backslash\{0\}$, we have the identity
$$
\delta_0\left(t^2-|x|^2\right)=\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2} t} \mathrm{~d} \sigma_{C_0^{+}}(t, x)
$$
where $C_0^{+}:=\{(t, x): t=|x|, t \geq 0\}$ is a forward cone and $\mathrm{d} \sigma_{C_0^{+}}$is the induced measure on $C_0^{+}$.
Proof:
For a test function $f(x_1,x_2,x_3,t),$ then for an approximation for delta function, for example $$\delta '(x)=\frac{1}{h} 1_{|x|\leq \frac{h}{2}},$$ then $$\langle\delta'(t^2-|x|^2),f(x,t)\rangle=\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{R^3}\frac{1}{h} 1_{ [ ||x|^2-t^2|\leq \frac{h}{2}]}f(x,t) \,dx \,dt$$
this is equivalent to\begin{align*}
    &\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{R^3}\frac{1}{h} 1_{ [ ||x|^2-t^2|\leq \frac{h}{2}]}f(x,t) \,dx \,dt \\
    &=\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{\sqrt{t^2-\frac{h}{2}}}^{\sqrt{t^2+\frac{h}{2}}}\frac{1}{h}f(r,\theta,\phi,t)r^2 \sin(\phi) \,dr \,d\phi \,d\theta \,dt
\end{align*}
when $h$ tends to $0^+$, the integral can be rewritten as $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sqrt{t^2+\frac{h}{2}}-\sqrt{t^2-\frac{h}{2}}}{h}f(\sqrt{t^2-\frac{h}{2}}+o(1),\theta,\phi,t)(\sqrt{t^2-\frac{h}{2}})^2 \sin(\phi) \,d\phi \,d\theta dt$$, notice that while $h$ tends to $0^+,$ we have
$$\frac{\sqrt{t^2+\frac{h}{2}}-\sqrt{t^2-\frac{h}{2}}}{h}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2+\frac{h}{2}}+\sqrt{t^2-\frac{h}{2}}},$$
which tends to $\frac{1}{2t}$, hence the above integral tends to $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{t}{2}f(t,\theta,\phi,t) \sin(\phi)\,d\phi \,d\theta dt.$$
Denote the above as $(1).$ Now consider $\mathrm{~d} \sigma_{C_0^{+}}(t, x)$
the parameterization of the this forward cone is $$
(x_1,x_2,x_3,t=\sqrt{x_{1}^2+x_{2}^2+x_{3}^2}),$$ hence the hypersurface element is $$\mathrm{d} \sigma_{C_0^{+}}=\sqrt{1+|\triangledown(t(x_1,x_2,x_3))  |^2}=\sqrt{2}$$
hence we have $$\langle\mathrm{d} \sigma_{C_0^{+}}, f(x,t)\rangle=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{C_0^{+}} \sqrt{2}f(x,t) \,dx\,dt=\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\sqrt{2}t^{2}f(t,\theta,\phi,t) \sin(\phi)\,d\phi \,d\theta \,dt.$$
Compare this to $(1),$ we prove the result.

Please point out any thing wrong about this proof, thank you very much

Please add some context or a source for "Lemma 4.10".

@MarcShelikoff this is from a lecture on wave equation , but the original proof in this pdf is hard to understand https://math.berkeley.edu/~sjoh/pdfs/linearWave.pdf

Is the stated identity really true? Left hand side has support on both the forward and backward cones, but doesn't the right hand side only have support on the forward cone?

$\mathrm{d} \sigma_{C_0^{+}}=\sqrt{1+|\triangledown(t(x_1,x_2,x_3))  |^2}=\sqrt{2}$ is missing differentials, e.g. $dx_1, dx_2, dx_3.$
